# Is loading both release and debug version of MSVCR (or UCRT etc.) officially supported by MS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, msvcrt

When you link to the [MS Visual C Runtime Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from your (C++) program, you normally only link against one version, the release or debug version: Either `MSVCR<ver>.dll` or `MSVCR<ver>D.dll`or [with VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) the `ucrtbase[D].dll`s and their additional dependencies.

**Disclaimer:** Mixing their *usage* and exchanging pointers (etc.) from one to the other will lead to crashes and insanity -- this is *not* what this question is about.

However, when your C or C++ program links to a 3rd party (C) DLL that is only delivered in a release variant, and that DLL uses MSVCR *internally*(!), it will link to and load the release version, even when you run your program in the debug version. (A variant of this is that the 3rd party lib could, again *internally*, also use a completely different MSVCR###.dll version than you, in which case they'd differ even in your release build.

This is a pretty standard scenario for me, and I always assumed that this "just works" (which indeed it seems it *does*).

I've been wondering however, whether this is actually an expected and supported scenario for these MS libraries? Is it? Any experiences to the contrary?

Comment: Aside Link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1fef65a6-17c8-47de-a3a9-7271c7e3d368/mfc-compatibility-different-mfc-versions-loaded-in-the-same-process?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is supported, and is common.

For example, if you build a C++/CLI Windows Forms app, you'll probably end up loading at least three different CRTs into the process:  your program will use msvcr.dll, the CLR will use msvcr120_clr0400.dll, and various operating system components loaded in your process may use msvcrt.dll.

Comment: Thanks James for letting us know! I'm fine with that answer ... but is there maybe any explicit mention of this in MSDN docs? Cheers.

Comment: I've recently wondered about a related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178865/use-c-dlls-from-the-same-vs-compiled-at-different-times-teams-abi-compatibil