# Oracle OCI.dll statically links to MSVCR100.dll - will it work with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: windows, oracle, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, oracle-call-interface

Our (native) C++ app accesses an Oracle Database through [OCI](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/toc.htm). (**not** [OCCI](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/toc.htm))

We're currently compiling on VS2010. We want to migrate our code base to VS2015, and while it seems implied that OCI should work there, I noticed that the [12c Version of the OCI.dll](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/instantclient/121020/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip) statically links to [MSVCR100.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.100).aspx), which is the dynamic CRT lib of Visual Studio 2010.

Should I expect OCI 12c (Instant Client) access to work through a native C++ app compiled with the VS2015 toolset? (Or any Visual-C++ version newer that 2010, really.)

Our app would use the MSVCR* libs of 2015, and the OCI.dll would continue to ose the MSVCR100, which is [not a problem in principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36727785/321013).

---

Disclaimer: Personally, I'd say: hell yes, sure it should work, but I can't find any official support statement (probably temporary search blindness), *and* I'm not really fluent with the full OCI API so I'm not sure whether there are corner cases where invalid stuff could be passed.